# Memory management in javascript

Tags: javascript, scope

I am trying to develop an application using javascript and to help organise my code, I am coding using objects. However, I don't really understand how the javascript engine is managing my object.

If in a first HTML `page1` where I include a js file, I make an object `obj1` when I switch to HTML `page2` where I include both the old js script (already included in the first html page ) and the second js file where I want to use that object created in the first javascript file, it's `undefined`.

Can anyone help me understand how javascript manages objects and how, going from page to page, to get my object ?

Comment: As soon as you (re)load a page, all the JS is reset. Just some properties like `localStorage` are persisted between page calls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you load a new page (or even reload the current one), *everything* that was on the page you are leaving is *destroyed*.

If you want to make an object persistent, consider using `localStorage` to save the information you need.